# Default return error for white label erorr

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I have this controller which is open when user is redirected.

```
@Controller()
public class RedirectController {

      @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/redirect")
      @ResponseBody
      public String handleRedirectMessage(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
          ......
      }
}
```

But when the match is not found I get `Whitelabel Error Page`. Is there some way to set default handler which is by default open when path is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need add following property:

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

And implement `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController` interface and overrides its getErrorPath() to return a custom path to call when an error occurred:

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController  {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError() {
        //do something like logging
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

After that add error page for path "/error" Thymeleaf `error.html`.

Also you could add pager for different errors:

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

    if (status != null) {
        Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

        if(statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
            return "error-404";
        }
        else if(statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
            return "error-500";
        }
    }
    return "error";
}
```

You can find here full code [example](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/com/baeldung/errorhandling/controllers) 
and [description](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page).